# Icon.button are working but Icon.ToolbarAndroid are not working in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-android

Im trying to get work Material Icon.ToolbarAndroid  on React Native App but its not working

```
Info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: Linux 5.0 Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo)
    CPU: (6) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz
    Memory: 1.89 GB / 15.61 GB
    Shell: 5.0.3 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.15.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/node
    npm: 6.12.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.3/bin/npm
  SDKs:
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 27, 28
      Build Tools: 27.0.3, 28.0.3
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
    react-native: 0.61.0-rc.3 => 0.61.0-rc.3 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

This is my code

```
<Icon.ToolbarAndroid
                navIconName={
                  activeRoute.name === routes[0].name ? "menu" : "arrow-left"
                }
                titleColor="#fff"
                title={activeRoute.name}
                onIconClicked={
                  activeRoute.name === routes[0].name ? showMenu : goBack
                }
                overflowIconName="dots-vertical"
                style={{ height: 56 }}
                actions={[
                  { title: "About", show: "never", iconName: "information-outline" },
                  { title: "Credits", show: "never", iconName: "account-circle" }
                ]}
                onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}
                iconColor={'white'} iconSize={24} logoName={'home'}/>
```

Here you can find the error

https://ibb.co/Y8JtyC5

Comment: could you show you code and describe what  happened

Comment: @Lenoarod I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors often occur due to typos or improper importing. Can you post the entirety oof your index.js file?

Comment: here you can find my app.js
https://pastebin.com/qr7ZQvkk
Index is here
https://pastebin.com/3FUJXX9L